# Unable to redirect NewForm.aspx to another page

Tags: 2013, forms-7

I am using SharePoint 2013 OP with SharePoint Designer 2013.

I created a Custom List to recieve problem reports. Using SPD 2013 I created a "NewForm.aspx" and used the following code for a redirect to a thank you / confirmation page:

<SharePoint:SaveButton  RedirectUrl="http://mysitecollection/Pages/Thank-You.aspx" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>

When the user submits the form and hits save, the form resets and clears. It does not actually redirect to the page specified.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Server side' Save Button, use the **input** button and **ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent** to navigate to the custom page as shown below.

```
With a custom data validation function(), ValidateData():

<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript:if( ValiateData() ){ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={','http://mysitecollection/Pages/Thank-You.aspx','}'))}"></input>

Without a custom data validation function:

<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript:{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={','http://mysitecollection/Pages/Thank-You.aspx','}'))}"></input>
```

Comment: I tried this. The re-direct worked using the default new item form. When I tried to put that form into a blank .aspx page via SPD it just resets

Comment: Actually nevermind, this worked perfectly. Thank You!!!